# Impact of a 'bad' tech stack on my career?

Tags: career-development, software-development, software, job-hopping, software-engineering

I recently switched job (I used to be a tech lead working with recent technologies such as Java 11, AWS, Spring boot, Kubernets (EKS), Terraform, etc). Now I work for a startup as a software engineer with Java 8 (working on a JDBC driver) - so java is basically the only tech I work with.
I am concerned about this move as I feel that I'm not learning much but I can't change job as I already have a few short experiences and it would look bad on my CV.
I like the company but I feel that staying would be bad for my career - but leaving would be bad too !
I would like to have some points of view/suggestions about what I should do. Thanks !

Comment: We don't give advice on what you should do - as we don't know who you are or what is important to you.

Comment: Focus on your Leetcode, not the tech stack. A good developer will be able to adapt to different tech stacks easily. If you're really that worried, spend some of your free time on getting certified in AWS or something else.

Comment: Tech stack shouldn't matter. Programming languages are easy to pick up, especially once you already have one or two under your belt. Most jobs would care more about your ability to learn new technologies (and *maybe* what technologies you already know) than "what is the last tech stack you used".

Answer (score 5):

There's more to a job than a simple technology stack.

Try to pause for a while and think about your surrounding - what are you learning? If the tech stack isn't great, in what other manner are you growing?

When you come to more senior positions, the tech stack will be less and less important. What will be more important is your experience with different business cases, stakeholders, release management, product management, etc, basically, understanding your clients better - that's the time you become a consultant. So every experience counts, just be aware of what are you learning at the moment. If it's nothing, it probably means you've either outgrew the problem or you're not aware of it - then, try to seek advice from colleagues to find out which is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this indirectly first:

There are still people who specialize in forging and making bladed tools, despite Mankind doing this for *Thousands* of years.

There are still ways to learn and master a old Tech that is applicable in the modern age, even in Computing.

With is being a Start-up, there is a more than likely chance that there are going to be unanticipated challenges that you will need to overcome - the process by which you overcome these will be the learning experience, not the specific lines of Code that were written.

If you are hyper-career focused (and it's cool if you are) and you have timeframes and set technologies that you want to have on your Resume, then you know the answer - look elsewhere.

Whereas me, personally, I would look to the Start-Up environment as a chance to grow into more senior roles that may or may not exist at the company yet and I'd focus on doing the best job possible. With a bit of time, there may even be scope for incorporating the new hotness technologies to your product (like Docker-izing or making it portable to the cloud or similar)

Comment: ...and this is how we end up with pieces of software that could be simple packages but are Dockerized anyway.